# restful service request / response timestamp logging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, logging

I have a Restful service using an asp.net WebApp running on a Windows 10 server. I would like the request / responses logged in the server somewhere. The minimum information I need is request ID, timestamp, data passed, response timestamp and response data.

How do I achieve this ? Any suggestions. It is getting difficult sometimes to trace requests and responses.

Answer (score 1):

if your are host the application on IIS then it will automatically maintan the log file.

at path.
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles

Comment: Thank you. I see the response has a structure like this

200 0 0 249 and some more responses like

200 0 0 941
200 0 0 282


what are the numbers 282, 941 etc., ? are these the time it has taken in mSec ?

Comment: My responses are a bit delayed... so am wondering how to measure the time between receiving a request to sending a response - this is the time taken by my rest service. 

Any ideas on how to measure this ?

Comment: Open Your IIS, Select you application, select option Logging( Under IIS Head), Click on Select Field button, there you can find lot of option under that you can also find the Time Taken option.

Comment: Thank you. Good answer. I was able to choose different parameters from the logs